# Neural network library for Python for Microsoft Windows

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-mining, python

I have been having trouble with selecting a good library for Neural network algorithms in Python.

- TensorFlow isn't supported on windows.
- Theano is still in the beta phase of development.
- PyBrain too is in the beta phase of development.
- Scipy supports machine leaning in terms of regression and clustering. But neural networks aren't present.

Please suggest me a reliable and robust library.

Comment: Where did you see that Theano  is still in the beta phase of development?

Comment: The latest verison is still listed as 0.8.2.
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/

Comment: good catch :) I have been using it for years, the first time I realized it's technically in beta. (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Theano lists it as "Development Status :: 4 - Beta")

Comment: Does this mean that there isn't an industry vetted, credible library for neural networks and machine learning in python?

Comment: Tensorflow supports Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTNK https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK which is actively developed by Microsoft. Blog post: https://blogs.microsoft.com/next/2016/01/25/microsoft-releases-cntk-its-open-source-deep-learning-toolkit-on-github/

It supports [Keras](https://keras.io/) which means that you can manage to run a Keras script backed by CTNK. Thus, it is also easy to take a Keras script backed by Tensorflow and run with it CTNK.

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly used neural network libraries are Caffe, TensorFlow, Theano, and Torch. TensorFlow officially supports Microsoft Windows.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_deep_learning_software and [best python library for neural networks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/694/843) give a more comprehensive list.

---

FYI:

- [How to install Theano on Anaconda Python 2.7 x64 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687103/395857)
- [Installing pre-built mxnet packages on Windows](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/docs/how_to/build.md#building-on-windows)
- [Microsoft's Caffe port for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/caffe)

Comment: I see many of these libraries also provide support for mac OS. Is there a reason for leaving out windows specifically?

Comment: @AnkitBansal just easier to maintain a single OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scikit-learn for neural networks with backpropagation

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html